# React website and When I refresh a page on azure it show 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, reload, custom-error-pages

my website is on `React` and when I refresh a page it shows `404 found` find. I tried many times but have not got a solution yet.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check all services , sometimes due to this just might be the issue